# how ineffecient is it using Popen with pipes vs mysql module in python?

Tags: python

i am doing a data migration and i am doing the code below in several places. it was migrated some what from some bash stuff so it works, but wondering if it's more efficient to be using the mysql module, thanks.

```
    p1 = Popen(["echo", query], stdout=PIPE, close_fds=True)

    p2 = Popen(["mysql", "--host=host", "--port=3999",
        "-u", "user", "--password=foo", "--protocol=TCP"],
        stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE, close_fds=True)

    p1.stdout.close()
```

`

```
p1 = Popen(["echo", "show columns from %s" % (table)], stdout=PIPE,
        close_fds=True)

p2 = Popen(["mysql", "--host=host", "--port=3999",
    "-u", "user", "--password=foo", "--protocol=TCP"],
    stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE, close_fds=True)

p3 = Popen(["awk", "{print $1}"], stdin=p2.stdout, stdout=PIPE,
        close_fds=True)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what you are trying to do. If you do not need to process the result in Python, then it may actually be faster to use subprocess.

[image]

On this graph the y-axis is in units of seconds, the x-axis represents the number of rows of data selected.

Note that the comparison is not entirely fair:
`using_subprocess` returns a string, while `using_mysqldb` returns a list of tuples. The added time it takes Python to create those Python objects certainly accounts for at least some of the difference in speed.

---

There is no compelling reason to write shell-style scripts in Python using `subprocess`. You might be better off just writing a shell script.

If you need to use Python to process the **string** returned by `mysql`, then you could make the code much more readable using the [sh module](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/sh/), rather than `subprocess`.

---

```
import config
import subprocess
import shlex
import timeit
import MySQLdb
import collections
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Popen = subprocess.Popen
PIPE = subprocess.PIPE
sql = 'select * from table limit {n}'

def using_subprocess(n):
    p1 = Popen(
        shlex.split(
            'echo {s}'.format(s=sql.format(n=n))), stdout=PIPE, close_fds=True)

    p2 = Popen(
        shlex.split(
            'mysql --host={h} -u {u} --password={p} --database={d}'.format(
                h=config.HOST,
                u=config.USER,
                p=config.PASS,
                d=config.MYDB
                )),
        stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE, close_fds=True)

    p1.stdout.close()
    out, err = p2.communicate()
    return out

def using_mysqldb(n):
    connection = MySQLdb.connect(
        host = config.HOST, user = config.USER,
        passwd = config.PASS, db = config.MYDB)
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute(sql.format(n=n))
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    return rows

times = collections.defaultdict(list)
ns = [10**i for i in range(5)]
for n in ns:
    times['using_mysqldb'].append(
        timeit.timeit('m.using_mysqldb({n})'.format(n=n),
                      'import __main__ as m',
                      number = 10))
    times['using_subprocess'].append(
        timeit.timeit('m.using_subprocess({n})'.format(n=n),
                      'import __main__ as m',
                      number = 10))

for name, time in times.iteritems():
    plt.plot(ns, time, label=name)
    # print('{n}: {t}'.format(n=name, t=time))
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Comment: what i do with the result from mysql is write it to disk at the /dev/shm then upload it to S3. so i don't process the result set at all, just move it from here to there.